# BlueJ terminal not updating values in real time

Tags: java, bluej

I am programming in BlueJ and i have a problem regarding the fields. The problem is that the field values do not update in real time, only when i close the terminal window. What i am trying to do is create abattleground where monsters and players fight each other, but when they attack each other the field values such as health does not decrease.

this part of the code is from the Player class:

```
public int damageMonster(Monsters monster) {
    int damage = minDamage + randomGenerator.nextInt(maxDamage-minDamage);
    monster.changeHealth(-damage);
    return damage;
}
```

This part of the code is from the Battleground class:

```
public void start() {
    boolean finished = false;

    printWelcome();

    while(!finished) {
        String input = reader.getInput().trim().toLowerCase();

        if(input.startsWith("run")) {
            finished = true;
        }
        if(input.startsWith("attack")) {
            System.out.println(player1.getName()+ " and " + randomBeast.getType()+ " enter the arena");            
            System.out.println(player1.getName()+ " deals " + player1.damageMonster(randomBeast) + " damage.");
            System.out.println(randomBeast.getType() + " deals " + randomBeast.damagePlayer(player1) + " damage");
        } else if(input.startsWith("run")) {
            System.out.println(player1.getName() + " left the match and lost 50 gold");
            //player1.getGold()= player1.getGold()-50;
        } else { 
            System.out.println("You need to insert one of the commands mentioned above");
        } 
    }
}
```